# Mapping a single row with a BLOB column using iBatis is very slow

Tags: java, sql, oracle, blob, ibatis

Please help me crack this issue, basically a single row is being retrieved from a Oracle db that contains a BLOB column (size of the BLOB is about 350k) and map to a Java object using iBatis 2.5 but the mapping part (result is mapped to a resultmap) is taking around 40 seconds to be complete. Do you maybe know what can be the bottleneck in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find a bottleneck on the Oracle side is to examine the wait events of the session running the SQL.  Use v$session and or v$active_session_history (if AWR is licesned).
Sometimes "idle" wait events on the Oracle side point to bottlenecks on client or network.